# The data I am returning does not affect the inside of the void function protected override

Tags: c#, opengl, overriding, opentk

I'm sending a bitmap frame to the "Load" function below. The LoadTexture function returns the data as "1" in GenTexture and sets it to texture. When I debug I see that texture returns "1". But it does not affect the data in the "OnRenderFrame" function. I have to use the OnRenderFrame with protected override.

```
public void Load(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    texture = LoadTexture(bitmap);
}

public int LoadTexture(Bitmap file)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = file;
    int tex;

    GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

    GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);

    BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Luminance, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
        OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Luminance, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
    bitmap.UnlockBits(data);


    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
    return tex;
}


protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    Title = $"(Vsync: {VSync}) FPS: {1f / e.Time:0}";

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    DrawImage(texture);
    Console.WriteLine(texture);
    SwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: Where's `texture` defined? What data type is it - `int`? This code looks incomplete..

Comment: @CoolBots  private int texture;

Comment: Are you sure the functions run in the order you think they do? Is it possible something else is changing the value? Can you add an `if(texture == 1) { ; }` in your `OnRenderFrame`, place a breakpoint on the line with the semicolon - does it hit?

Comment: no, it doesn't even hit once. On the other hand, the texture increases as the frame comes in. "1,2,3,4, ...." @CoolBots

Comment: @CoolBots I guess the thread where I sent the data and onrenderframe are not in the same thread. There is no link between the two functions.

Comment: @CoolBots I think I found the trouble. I run the Opentk gamewindow as mainwindow.run (). When I run the data after sending it, the data was displayed. But I can't change texture after running.